# The connection was reset issue in all browsers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, browser, iis-6

I am getting "The connection was reset" issue in all browser.

Below is details shown in Mozilla Firefox.

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

- The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
- If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
- If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

As per suggestion available in Google, I have done browser reset, open the site in safe mode. Done with IIS reset.

But till no luck :(

Getting same issue in all browsers. Below is 2 screenshots.

[image: Error in Google chrome]

[image: Error in IE]

Any suggestion?

Comment: This issue happening only for my project. No other site have the issue. So I don't think there is internet issue.

Comment: URLs? Code? Do static files work? If even static files don't work...

Comment: Try creating a test file and see if you can access it. Is this definitely [tag:asp-classic]?

Comment: Yes, static file work. In current file, we have a check box and a button. Initially the button is hidden. When user check the check-box, the button get visible. Here we get above issue.  Below code get executed after check-box checked.                                                                                          If Request.Form("chkAcceptT&C") <> "" Then
 btnDisplay = "block" // Here we set visible flag for the button.
End If

Comment: Attaced screenshot of error that I am getting in IE and Google chrome.

Comment: Possible reasons may be you are transmitting heavy amount of data and the request times out. try disabling  data and load the empty page.

Comment: No, there is very few data.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and I managed to solve it. The problem is the ip version.

Solution:

- Press: windows_key + R
- Type:  ncpa.cpl
- Right click => Properties (of whatever connection you are connected to)
- Uncheck 'Internet Protocol Version 6 (TPC/IPv6)'
- Hit 'Ok'

Now reload the page and it should open without any problem.